# How to install NVIDIA GeForce 610M on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: graphics, intel

root@wruslanAC-bismillah-rtai:~/Downloads/Linux-Drivers-ACER-4752G/xf86-video-intel-2.14.0# uname -a
Linux wruslanAC-bismillah-rtai 2.6.32-122-rtai #rtai SMP Tue Jul 27 12:44:07 CDT 2010 i686 GNU/Linux

root@wruslanAC-bismillah-rtai:~/Downloads/Linux-Drivers-ACER-4752G/xf86-video-intel-2.14.0# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0104 (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 0126 (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point HECI Controller #1 (rev 04)
...
...
root@wruslanAC-bismillah-rtai:~/Downloads/Linux-Drivers-ACER-4752G/xf86-video-intel-2.14.0# ./configure
checking for XORG... no
configure: error: Package requirements (xorg-server >= 1.6 xproto fontsproto ) were not met:

No package 'xorg-server' found
No package 'fontsproto' found
....
....
root@wruslanAC-bismillah-rtai:~/Downloads/Linux-Drivers-ACER-4752G/xf86-video-intel-2.14.0# apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version.
....
....

Thank you.
WRY

Answer (score 2):

There has been a recent certified driver release, you may have to do a manual install:
[Linux x64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver, Version: 304.51 Certified](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-304.51-driver.html)

You may have to manually install, here is how I did it on an older legacy vid card, the code should be similar:
[Driver Installation](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11951878&postcount=13)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `nvidia-current` and see if that fixes it.  nvidia-current is the current version of the drivers as of Lucid (there's a newer version in precise if you want to upgrade, but that'll possibly break other things).

Answer (score 0):

The [driver package in 10.04 is to old](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/lucid-updates/nvidia-current) and does not support series 600 cards.

In this particular case the [Ubuntu X-Swat PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) might be actually of help since it provides current driver packages for 10.04.